# Where is my virtual machine phsically is?

Tags: vagrant

Now I have a `Vagrantfile` and I can boot the virtual machine through it.

```
vagrant up
[default] VM already created. Booting if it's not already running...
```

But I want to know where its image is(physically). The directory where `Vagrantfile` is contains only:

```
ls -a
.. .git .gitignore .vagrant Vagrantfile
```

They're obviously not the image file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Vagrant docs](http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/boxes.html):

Downloaded boxes are here:

Linux/Mac

`~\.vagrant.d\boxes`

Windows

`%UserProfile%\.vagrant.d\boxes`

The VM disks are here:

Linux/Mac

`~\VirtualBox VMs`

Windows

`%UserProfile%\VirtualBox VMs`